# DNA pairing, arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am relatively young developer and I'm confused about few things.

Here is my code:

```
function pairElement(str) {

    var arr = [];
    var pairs = [
     ["A","T"],
     ["T","A"],
     ["C","G"],
     ["G","C"]
    ];

    var spl = str.split("");

    for(var i = 0; i<pairs.length; i++){
        for(var j= 0; j<spl.length; j++){
            if(pairs[i][0] == spl[j]){
                arr.push(pairs[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    return arr;
}
pairElement("ATCGA");
```

The problem is that the function gives me back this array:  [["A","T"],["A","T"],["T","A"],["C","G"],["G","C"]]

I have all the pairs but the new array is giving me results in the order I wrote the pairs array, why is that?

Comment: Could you describe the expected behavior of your function?

Comment: if a call it with  pairElement("AT") i get pairs AT, TA but if a call it with  pairElement("TA"); i get the same result..

Comment: Ok, I think I get it. If I'm not mistaken the order of your result is based on the order of your `pairs` array because your outer `for` loop iterate over that array, rather than on the input string. I think you could simply inverse your two for loops and get your expected result.

Comment: Switching the loops corrects the mistake

Comment: true, done! thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion, for a shorter access to the array with the pairs. You could use an object and use the letter as key.

```js
function pairElement(str) {
    var pairs = {
        A: ["A","T"],
        T: ["T","A"],
        C: ["C","G"],
        G: ["G","C"]
    };

    return str.split("").map(function (a) { 
        return pairs[a];
    });
}

console.log(pairElement("ATCGA"));
```

Comment: thank you.. i have tried something with the map() function  but it was more important for me to understand "how the things work" :)